# Subclassing UIScrollView vs UIView for custom view with multiple view hierarchies

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiscrollview

This is my first attempt at writing a custom view with column, rows and sections.
Inside my sections view I have two scrollviews -->headerView and gridView

Here is the view hierarchy I have setup:
GridView(UIScrollview subclass)
---->contains subview-->GridViewSection(UIView subclass with UIScrollViewDelegate)
------>contains subviews-->headerView and gridView

I also have a custom GridViewCell class that populates each scrollView with rows and columns that can scroll left,right,up and down like a spreadsheet.

I was wondering if this is the best approach or should my GridView container be a subclass of UIView instead of UIScrollView?